# During our review of your extension we found that the Info.plist is missing the ‘Website' field while submitting to safari extension gallery

Tags: safari, macos-high-sierra, safari-extension, dmg

While submitting the safari extension in Safari extension gallery I am getting the query of  During our review of your extension we found that the Info.plist is missing the ‘Website' field.

URL is already mentioned in the plist file.

info.plist

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Author</key>
    <string>OpenText</string>
    <key>Builder Version</key>
    <string>13606.2.104</string>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>DCMExtension</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.emc.documentum.CTF</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.1</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1</string>
    <key>Chrome</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Global Page</key>
        <string>global.html</string>
    </dict>
    <key>Content</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Scripts</key>
        <dict>
            <key>End</key>
            <array>
                <string>ContentScript.js</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>Description</key>
    <string>Assists in content transfer of files in xCP, D2 and Webtop applications</string>
    <key>DeveloperIdentifier</key>
    <string>4B9GHJ9X43</string>
    <key>ExtensionInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>Permissions</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Website Access</key>
        <dict>
            <key>Include Secure Pages</key>
            <true/>
            <key>Level</key>
            <string>All</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>URL</key>
    <string>https://raw.github.com/d2user/safari/master/DCMExtension.safariextz</string>
    <key>Update From Gallery</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I just had one more doubt that while submitting the extension it was asking about the website in submission form 
[submission in safari extension gallery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xnAa6.png)

I am keeping the website blank, is that is causing the problem and do I need to mention just the website of the product or from where we are downloading it.

Does it also have any references for that in the `info.plist`? Any hint on this!!!

Answer (score 0):

We need to add website in the info.plist

```
<key>Website</key>
<string>https://github.com/spadin/js-beautify-safari-extension</string>
```

https://github.com/spadin/js-beautify-safari-extension/blob/master/Info.plist